# What is this.loading = false?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

I am using Laravel and Vue.
When I was searching on the internet I saw the following code.

```
<template>
<div>
<h3 class="text-center">Create Movie</h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<form @submit.prevent="createMovie">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="movie.name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Director</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="movie.director">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create movie</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            movie: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createMovie() {

            this.axios
                .post('http://localhost:8000/api/movie/create', this.movie)
                .then(response => (
                    this.$router.push({name: 'movie'})
                ))
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
                .finally(() => this.loading = false)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to find out what the last line

```
.finally(() => this.loading = false)
```

is doing. I am searching on the internet but I can't find what it does. Also, I tried running the code without the last line however, it did not make any change.

Can someone please tell me what this is doing and when it is useful?

Comment: this.loading refers to the same thing as this.movie -> to the return object in data method. Whoever wrote the code you found online probably forgot to declare it there, but used it afterwards

Comment: Then in Vue, does it not throw an error assigning a value to an object that does not exist?

Comment: In this case, the object it is assigning a value to is just the component context `this`. You can add properties to `this` at any stage but unless they are first declared in the `data()` object they will not be reactive.

Comment: But when I console.log(this.loading) it returns undefined. Does that not mean it is not declared?

Comment: @Coder Yes, you would want to add `loading: false` to your `data()`.

Comment: But why does it not give me an error when I assign false to this.loading that does not exist? Is that normal behavior?

Comment: It is normal behavior. You are creating the `loading` property when you assign the value `false` to it. If try to print the value of `this.loading` before `createMovie()` is called, then it will be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the associated Vue template we cannot explain what it is doing exactly, however, we can be fairly confident that the value of `loading` will be used to show/hide some sort of overlay or activity spinner.

The purpose of the overlay/activity spinner is to provide visual feedback to the user that something is happening. This is useful when loading large amounts of data into your page, or when you perform a long running process (such as uploading a large file for example). So rather than the user seeing nothing on first page load, or clicking a button and wondering if it worked, they are provided with something to let them know that something is happening.

A basic example of what this might look like in the Vue template could be:

```
// if the value of loading is true, show this
<div v-if="this.loading">Loading, please wait ...</div>
// otherwise show this
<div v-else>Other content</div>
```

Your example is setting the value of `loading` to `false` once a response has been received from your axios request. You would probably want to set the value of `loading` to `true` prior to making the request to show an overlay/activity spinner.

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ture is not defined

You have a typo, it should be `true` not `ture`.

Comment: I edited my question and added the whole code

Comment: @Coder It appears `loading` is never used. You would be safe removing the `finally` statement in your `axios` request, or you could implement the `loading` functionality yourself if you want to.

Comment: But why does it not give me an error when I assign false to this.loading that does not exist? Is that normal behavior?